# Access to protected members of base class with CRTP

Tags: c++, protected, derived-class, crtp

I would like to ask you a question about the CRTP.
Suppose you have a base class and a derived class as below.
Is there a way to extract the member "value" from the base class in one of the member functions of the derived class (e.g., "foo")?

The compiler tells me:
   error: ‘value’ was not declared in this scope

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, class Implementation>
class FooBase
{
protected:
   void fooBase(void) {};
   int value;
};

template <class T>
class Foo : public FooBase <T, Foo<T>>
{
  friend FooBase <T, Foo<T>>;

  public:
  void foo()
  {
    std::cout << "Its own value is : " << value << std::endl;
  }
};

int main ()

{
  Foo <int> foo;
  foo.foo();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a problem except that `value` is not initialized. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.8.2, but from what I learnt from the answer below, I forgot to use the "this". Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are directly inheriting from a base class that depends on `T` you need to use `this->` to access your data members:

```
std::cout << "Its own value is : " << this->value << std::endl;
//                                    ^^^^^^
```